# Create a new column of lists in Pandas dataframe with unique values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of lists:

```
    full_list_to_check
 0          NaN 
 1          NaN 
 2    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 3        [6, 6] 
 4        [11, 11]
```

I need to create a new column where it shows a distinct list for each row if duplicates exist in the list, otherwise just the same list.

```
  full_list_to_check            new_col
 0          NaN                   NaN
 1          NaN                   NaN
 2    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 3        [6, 6]                  [6]
 4        [11, 11]                [11]
```

I have tried this:

```
df['new_col'] = df['full_list_to_check'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: replace your nan value with empty string,  dataframe.fillna('', inplace = True). it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You must check `Nan`:

```
df['full_list_to_check'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)) if not np.any(pd.isna(x)) else np.nan)
```

Update:

```
df['full_list_to_check'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)) if x is not np.nan else np.nan)
```

```
0                NaN
1                NaN
2    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3                [6]
4               [11]
```

Comment: why `if not np.any(pd.isna(x))` instead of `if x is not np.nan`?

Comment: @deadvoid `pd.isna(x)` return list

Comment: @Mikhail just genuinely curious, if the purpose is to filter out `NaN` tho, why requires `[True, True, False, ...]`? I mean in this case it's all either NaN or list, if the goal is to make it more general so it can be applicable... I guess I'm just trying to wrap my head on it

Comment: @DimaFirst ah, okay.. I thought there's some reason I didn't know, like for performance or others :) but it's all good, just honestly curious

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['new_col'] = df.loc[~df['full_list_to_check'].isna(), 'full_list_to_check'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

```
full_list_to_check new_col
0 NaN              NaN
1 NaN              NaN
2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3 [6, 6]           [6]
4 [11, 11]         [11]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
df['new_col'] = df['full_list_to_check'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)) if isinstance(x,list) else x)
```

The other answers only works if there are no other values then lists or NaN in your data.